# Is there a way to create with a script a swift class and add properties in pre-build?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bash

Maybe this is dumb but here goes nothing:
I am curious if there is a way to create a swift class or struct based on a list of properties. 
Maybe have his script inserted somewhere in the build phases.
For example, have a local JSON file or something similar, to read from:

```
 {"className":"Person", "name":"string", "age":"int" }
```

would create the struct:

```
struct Person {
   let name: String
   let age: Int
}
```

Comment: The short answer is: **Yes there is**.

Comment: Yes of course you can write a parser for that, not sure how easy it would be to add them to a target though.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I'm don't know how, that's why I asked the question, could please give an example as well?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson haven't thought of that yet, good catch. The parser part I'm ok with, the file and class creation part I'm having problems with.

Comment: [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io) might be interesting to look at. Depending on your actual use-case, it might be sufficient.

Comment: @Alexander thanks, I think I came past solutions similar to this, but I need it to be automatically done when I build the project

Comment: @MihaiFischer I think you can make a solution based off the [`SwiftSyntax` library](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax). It's first party, so it should be kept up to date and well maintained, and it lets you manipulate/generate/serialize Swift syntax trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

gawk -F, '{

    for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; ++i)
    {
        split($i, arr, ":")
        
        match(arr[1], /"(.*)"/, mat)
        key=mat[1]
        
        match(arr[2], /"(.*)"/, mat)
        value=mat[1]

        if (key ~ /className/)
        {
            struct_name=value
        }
        else
        if (value != "")
        {
            contents[key]=value
        }
    }
}
END {
    print "struct "struct_name" {"
    for (key in contents)
    {
        print "\tlet "key": "contents[key]
    }
    print "}"
}' file
```

I have heard people say this alot that `jq` is better when dealing with json, but I have never tried that. So you should consider searching about `jq` if it helps.

The above `gawk` script should produce the desired output.

The same can be done with general `awk` or even normal `bash` scripts but doing it with `gawk` was a little easier.

All you need to do is redirect the output of the above scipt to the desired file. Like suppose you saved the script with name `parser`.

```
bash parser > pathtoyourapp/filename.swift
```

You can do the same in the above script as too like on the last line of script:

```
}' file > pathtoyourxcodeproject/controller/filename.swift
```

As you are making `swift` code, I assume you have a `mac`. You can install `gawk` by any of the package managers available for `mac`. The one I use is [macports](https://www.macports.org). After installing `macports`, you can install `gawk` by `sudo port install gawk`.

## UPDATE:

As mentioned in the comments by trojanfoe, the project navigator won't update just by adding the file to the project directory. I am not sure about how to do that.

What I found after searching the net, [this](https://github.com/zackslash/Xcode-Proj-Adder) seems to do the job.

Comment: It's been an while since I've seen an Awk script!  The OP will probably want the `.swift` files added to his Xcode project too...

Comment: @trojanfoe, Its a long time since I worked on swift. If I saved `.swift` file in the xcode project directory, does it reflect changes on `xcode` while working(like whatever it was called, some project navigator)?

Comment: @trojanfoe, thnks, I will update that in my answer. Probably someone else might know how to do that and they may post it.